# Switching items between d3 characters in diff regions?

Tags: diablo-iii

**THE ISSUE**

First, understand the background --> [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66267/how-do-diablo-iii-regions-work)

- I am Australian D3 player
- I didn't check region and started playing (it turns out it defaulted to European servers)
- Now I'm level 50 I tried to access RMAH, and get error message - **"No currencies available"**

Based on [this](http://sea.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-realmoney-auction-house-regional-access), currencies available for me are: USD, MXN, ARS, CLP and AUD(clearly my prefered currency-but anyway). After this it seems clear I should be playing in Americas all along-just I never knew that this was an option or that it was chosen for me...)

---

**SOLUTION?**

- Does **it** (**it**, the fact I started on Eurpoean server and just want to be able to sell items I pick up) matter?
- It seems I am unable to trade in european AH (even if i **didn't care** about different currencies).

**IDEA 1:**

- I understand that you can switch items between characters.
- Will this cover me, should I want to sell an item in RMAH?
- i.e. switch it to player in my region, sell from there ?

**NO MORE IDEAS:**

- Do I have any options available?
- Or is the only way to switch servers and invest another... <strike>i dunno what, 60-100+ hours to be able to access AH? Note at no point of course is the user asked when starting the game what server they want to play in. You're just supposed to know.</strike>

**IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:**:

- Currently my region is set to **European**
- When I click on RMAH I get **no currencies available**. I have not changed my region to American and tested, I wanted to suss out what my options are before making a change that I don't fully understand the consequences of (they're are a lot of sob stories on this subject)

Comment: That was awesome - 5 captcha's to post this... *sigh*

Comment: downvote me, and for what... asking a perfectly reasonable question

Comment: I think the downvote is because your question is kind of unclearly worded. Do you not have access to the American RMAH, since that is your home server (through being Australian)?

Comment: This is a poor question, it sounds like you're just venting. AUD is Aussie Dollar, so you should be able to sell throught the RMAH on American Servers.

Comment: Is anybody even reading my question! OMG! How can I sell on american servers if my character is in european server! that IS the question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canadian purchased Diablo 3 game back to Europe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75582/canadian-purchased-diablo-3-game-back-to-europe)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change regions?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66144/how-can-i-change-regions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users aren't consulted on their preferred region because it's set automagically. They've included the option to change it even thought it shouldn't be used very often.

Australians are supposed to be on the American servers, it's considered our closest server. It's also the only place you can sell items for Aussie dollars in the RMAH.

There is no way to transfer a character to another server. Also AFAIK, you can't transfer items between characters on different servers.

Comment: Well then, from your answer I surmise that: There exists a bug with there automagic region setter. I was placed against Europe but am Australian, and have **always** connected from australian ips. Am I then to surmise: No solution? Thank you for your answer(honest - no sarcasm).

Comment: @kindascrewedbyblizzard Welcome to the land of blizzard!

Comment: Haha :) well u r entirely correct. For whatever reason, I was not placed in the optimal region- and TBH quite painful since I only want to play the Barb + had got him all that way. I've restarted with nothing in America-after 2 hours tonight- **LVL 8**. I'm honestly not sure I'll stay thru recompleting Normal/Nightmare because i've essentially lost 200 or so hours + all my gear-and don't know I will be bothered keep playing-not sure I have the will for that time invstmnt for replaying the 2nd time. On the positive LOL now i've switched regions, my latency constantly 200ms.. not 400.. FU BLIZ!

Comment: @kindascrewedbyblizzard: Always join public games till you get to Inferno, much faster to level up imho. As for the EU server - have you thought of just selling for EUR or any other currency there, and going for Blizzard bucks so you get to buy other titles free? Better than nothing at all since you can't get the money out easily.

Comment: @Alok: As far as I understand it, he doesn't have access to any RMAH while on the EU server because Australian IPs are only allowed to trade on the American RMAH, so he'd only be able to sell for gold.